# mi lista no toma parámetros

Tags: java, lista, parametros

Estoy intentando hacer que los datos ingresado por medio de unos `JTextField`s los almacene en una lista para luego crear un reporte pero cree una clase la cual solo contiene el constructor con tres campos los getters y los setters, pero cuando creo un método en mi proyecto *main* me da este error "**type List does not take parameters**".

Todo esta echo en JAVA.

```
    public List<entrega> obtenerentrega() {
        List en = new LinkedList();

        return en;
    }
```

[image: ejemplo del error]

Comment: Si lo que quieres es hacer una lista del objeto `entrega`, se hace así: `List<entrega> lista = new ArrayList<> ();'

Comment: fijate ya probe de esa manera y me da el mismo error  de que tipo lista no toma parmetros   pero no se por que me da ese error

Comment: El error de la imagen te dice que no se puede convertir `LinkedList` a `List`, porque no puedes hacer un `LinkedList` y asignarlo como `List`, por eso te he propuesto esa solución.

Comment: si tienes razon fijate que eso ambos los puse como Linkedlist pero arriba en public me da este error mira "type List does not take parameters" no se si tu me puedas ayudar que no he logrado dar por que me da ese error

Comment: Puedes agregar el código completo de ese archivo?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Casi seguro que estás usando la clase [java.awt.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) en vez de la interfaz [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) y por eso no te deja asignarle una `LinkedList`.

Comment: si esa clase estoy utilizando justamente java.awt.list  probare esa que tu me dices

Comment: No debe "probar" simplemente, no debes usarla para lo que quieres hacer. Debes saber que la clase `java.awt.List` en una clase que define un control de interfaz gráfica de usuario, por lo que es un error conceptual usarla en el caso que expones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder realizar lo que deseas asegura que el import de la clase `List` es:

```
import java.util.List;
```

con esto podràs crear un `List` usando `LinkedList` lo cual es permitido, pero por el mensaje de error seguramente estas usando:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

esta es la razòn por la cual obtienes el error:

> incompatible types: LinkedList cannot be converted to List

Comment: tienes toda la razon amigo y mil gracias por tu ayuda ya me funciono como deberia de ser